# Make a field of an object unique to each object stored in an array list

Tags: java, arraylist, unique, bluej

So i have an array list that stores customers and ive been tasked with making it so that no customer can have the same ID

the code has a write method which writes a text file of all customers so ive been tasked with when the code is closed and the customers have been written to the file when the code is re opened and new customers are made and added to the list none of them can have the same ID as someone whos already on the list from a previous storing of customers

Here is some code:

This is the write data for the customer text files

```
public void writeCustomerData(String fileName)
throws FileNotFoundException
{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    for (Customer c: customerList)
    {
        String lineOfOutput = c.getCustomerID() + ", " + c.getTitle() + ", " + c.getFirstName() + ", " + c.getSurname() + ", " + c.getInitials();
        pw.println(lineOfOutput);
    }
    pw.close();
}
```

This is the constructor to add new customers

```
public Customer(String nSurname, String nFirstName, String nOtherInitials, String nTitle)
{
    customerID = "unknown";
    surname = nSurname;
    firstName = nFirstName;
    otherInitials = nOtherInitials;
    title = nTitle;
}
```

This is the code that stores the customers into the arrayList

```
public void storeCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    if (customer.getCustomerID().equalsIgnoreCase("unknown"))
    {
        customer.generateCustomerID("AB", 5);
    }
    customerList.add(customer);
}
```

This is the code that generates the IDs

```
public void generateCustomerID(String prefix, int length)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        rand = random.nextInt(10);
        prefix = prefix + Integer.toString(rand);

    }
    setID(prefix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly want you need to achieve you need to use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (*"A collection that contains no duplicate elements"*) to avoid duplicates.

So, every time you run the code you have to read all the lines from the file, create a Customer and store in the `Set`.
With `Set`, when you call `customerList.add(customer)` the Set itself will take care of avoid adding duplicates.
Set use the mothods `equals` and `hashCode` to check if a `Custom` is already in the `Set`, so be sure to properly implement these methods.

Answer (score 0):

> Generating random ID is not perhaps the good solution in this case.
> Try something like
>
> `String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`
>
> It generates fully random string.
>
> If you really need just random, is better to use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()`